# checkbox checked multiple time for selecting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have a checkbox that has to disable other textbox when set to true.
here  what actually problem is checkbox changes values  only when i clicked twice for first time. for first time i have to clicked to two times for disable other textbox. otherwise it's perfectly work fine. 
here i have given my jquery function :

```
function bundlecheckout(val,total)
{ 

   $("#file_check"+val).click(function() {
        $('input[id^="file_check"]').attr("checked", false);
        //$("#file_check"+val).unbind('click');
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
        $("#checkout").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
        for(i=0;i<=total+1;i++)
        {             
            if(i !=val ){           
            $("#txtinstruction"+i).attr("disabled", this.checked);
            $("#txturl"+i).attr("disabled", this.checked);
        }
        else{
            $("#txtinstruction"+i).removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#txturl"+i).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }   
   }    
);}
```

checkbox element

```
<input type="checkbox" class="file_check" name="file_upload_check" value="<?php echo $testing_type_id;?>" id="file_check<?php echo $testing_type_id;?>" onclick="bundlecheckout(<?php echo $testing_type_id;?>,<?php echo $total ?>);"/>Apply<br />
```

Comment: What's the point in posting PHP code?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, there's no PHP here.

Comment: Actually there is (otherwise I'd never come across such a question :). Yet there is absolutely no point in posting PHP code as PHP doesn't work with jquery.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, oh there's PHP in the html, but the question is about the jquery, I think you an safely ignore the php, just understand that it's echoing values.

Comment: Why are you binding click event on click itself?

Comment: You cannot ignore PHP as you plainly have no idea what can be echoed by PHP statements. That's why one **should** post not the PHP code but rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I don't know why you are binding click event on click itself.

```
function bundlecheckout(val,total,e)
    { 
            $('input[id^="file_check"]').attr("checked", false);
            //$("#file_check"+val).unbind('click');
            $(e).attr('checked', true);
            $("#checkout").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
            for(i=0;i<=total+1;i++)
            {             
                if(i !=val ){           
                $("#txtinstruction"+i).attr("disabled", this.checked);
                $("#txturl"+i).attr("disabled", this.checked);
            }
            else{
                $("#txtinstruction"+i).removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#txturl"+i).removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }   
      }
<input type="checkbox" class="file_check" name="file_upload_check" value="<?php echo $testing_type_id;?>" id="file_check<?php echo $testing_type_id;?>" onclick="bundlecheckout(<?php echo $testing_type_id;?>,<?php echo $total ?>,this);"/>Apply<br />
```